# something went wrong when I tried to use xrdp remote control

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection

I have a question: When I use XRDP for remote connection, I get the following error:

```
[20230823-20:42:47] [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(9, 6010) failed bind IPv6 (errno=98) and IPv4 (errno=22).
```

Upon checking, as shown in the screenshot, port 6010 is used by SSHD. However, strangely, my SSHD is clearly configured to listen on port 55555. Why is this happening?

[image]